# finding element in selenium webdriver code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image: css code]

How to find the web chat input message text for above. I tried few of options but none of them seems to work

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/bot-component/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[type='text]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[type='text]")
```

Comment: You want to find the element or the text?

Answer (score 0):

You should get value of attribute. Something like this.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[type='text]").get_attribute("type")`

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the value of Data=id?

```
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").get_attribute("data-id")
        print(element)
```

or you want to get the xpath locator on that tag?

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-id='webchat-sendbox-input']")
```

try putting this above the code:

```
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the `<input>` tag, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-id='webchat-sandbox-input'][@aria-label='Type your message']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-id='webchat-sandbox-input' and @aria-label='Type your message']")))
  ```